# How to create objects in server application and be able to call them from client application

Tags: java

I am learning to program Java. My objective is to create client server application based on Java and MySQL.
That would have following.

1. Server Application where all admin controls would be available to configure.
   server application will be the only to have access rights to MySQL.
2. Server will have all functions and objects that clients will require and call and get that functionality. (Reason for that is "I don't want to share MySQL credentials to client apps or rather i don't want MySQL credentials to be transmitted on the network to clients"). As it would increase maintenance tough and it could be a security loop hole.

An analogy of functionality could be: client calls to server telling to add an Order such `addOrder(order_id, payment,..,...,..)` and so on.

What are the method in practice for such kind of application these days? A example code/or material to get in right direction would suffice

Comment: What client are we talking here, is it a web application in which case the client will be the browser, or what?

Comment: I would have a server application that exposes a set of web services, probably RESTful servvices, implementing them using EJB's or CDI. Then, in client, I would just consume these services through the net (LAN, WAN, internet).

Comment: Hi ssayyed I am doing a native client application.

Comment: @ssayyed you didn't replied dear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These days the universal way to expose a service remotely is via a web service. This solution was preferred by the industry over time due to its simplicity and ease of integration to the point that binary based protocols like CORBA are now seldom used.

Take the example of Android applications, they are native application mostly using REST web services.

A REST web service can be easilly integrated in the same way with a desktop application, a mobile application or a web application, even if the clients are written in different native platforms and languages.

As sample code, have a look at tutorials on the Spring stack. For the server see this tutorial for building an [hello word REST web service](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-rest-hello-world-example/). For the client, consider the [REST template](https://spring.io/blog/2009/03/27/rest-in-spring-3-resttemplate).

For security, see this [Spring security hello world example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hello-world-example/). Using the Spring stack in Java will likelly give you the largest number of tutorials and online support.

Comment: Thanks i will what you have suggested as it gave me a direction

Comment: Im glad I could help. please consider marking the answer as accepted, these are some guidelines http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Oh i am sorry i am new to stake too sooory.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a good place to use RMI, which Java has built in support for. RMI will allow your client to call server-side methods on a local object that corresponds to the server, where all messages/commands get transparently sent to the actual server, where you have your DB access stuff and logic.

Comment: Hi Martin Dinov, What is method used for similar client server model. Is it RMI that is used? or Are there any other concepts used to achieve this? What i want is to have secure environment and can exercise configuration and control for server app. thankyou anyways